# SQL - Trying to sum values but only certain rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have an interesting problem that I can't quite figure out how to do. I need to total my values but I need to add the first two rows as a 'history' kind of view which will have a month end date of 1-31. Then I need to add each month, but each month is already summed so I am not how to pick and choose which items to sum to get the totals shown as listed below. Each month it will have a new month end date for the current year. This is not a typical summation problem because the amounts are already totaled for the 'new' year.

| MonthEnd | START_TS | END_TS | Amount | Totals(trying to get) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-31-21 | 1-31-19 | 1-31-20 | 200 | 200 |
| 1-31-21 | 1-31-20 | 1-31-21 | 200 | 400 |
| 2-28-21 | 1-31-21 | 2-28-21 | 10 | 410 |
| 3-31-21 | 2-28-21 | 3-31-21 | 17 | 417 |
| 4-30-21 | 3-31-21 | 4-28-21 | 25 | 425 |

I am using a type of postgresql. Is there anyway to do this in just SQL?

Comment: Is it always the first two of the table? If not, what identifies the first two of a group?

Comment: So the first of 'history' tables will have a TS of 1-31-XX that is less than the year 2021. and that will be the only records for the old years. Then starting the new year it will be each month.

Comment: What does "Then starting the new year it will be each month." mean exactly?

Comment: Starting in 2021 I have the new values which are already summed for each month. So I have to pick and select the old rows + the selected month for each record to get the correct summations.

Comment: Can you please update the question to include example rows that are "new", and add any details that might help clear it up? I'm having a hard time visualizing the data based on these comments.

Comment: Yes, I added a new column that would have been good to add at the start. Each column will have the month end date and all previous rows will have the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `SUM()` (for data up to 2020) + a `LAST_VALUE` (for data after 2020):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    "start_ts" TIMESTAMP,
    "end_ts"   TIMESTAMP,
    "amount"   INTEGER,
    "totals"   INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t
    ("start_ts", "end_ts", "amount", "totals")
VALUES ('1-31-19', '1-31-20', '200', '200')
     , ('1-31-20', '1-31-21', '200', '400')
     , ('1-31-21', '2-28-21', '10', '410')
     , ('2-28-21', '3-31-21', '17', '417')
     , ('3-31-21', '4-28-21', '25', '425')
     ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(amount) FILTER (WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_ts) < 2021) OVER (ORDER BY start_ts) +
       -- No FILTER for non-aggregate window functions, so a CASE will do
       CASE
           WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_ts) < 2021 THEN 0
           -- Not sure if your "amount" is sum per-year. If it's a rolling sum across years, remove the PARTITION
           ELSE LAST_VALUE(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_ts) ORDER BY start_ts)
       END AS sum
FROM t;
```

| start_ts | end_ts | amount | totals | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| 2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 200 | 400 | 400 |
| 2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z | 10 | 410 | 410 |
| 2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z | 17 | 417 | 417 |
| 2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z | 25 | 425 | 425 |

---

**Query #2**

If your "amount" is indeed the running sum *per year* (after 2020) then you can simply use `EXCLUDE TIES` to remove the other values from the same year:

```
SELECT *, SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_ts)
                            GROUPS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                            EXCLUDE TIES)
FROM t;
```

| start_ts | end_ts | amount | totals | sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 200 | 200 | 200 |
| 2020-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 200 | 400 | 400 |
| 2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z | 10 | 410 | 410 |
| 2021-02-28T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z | 17 | 417 | 417 |
| 2021-03-31T00:00:00.000Z | 2021-04-28T00:00:00.000Z | 25 | 425 | 425 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qPQ7KKg1VFXbHJfqDjzdQT/0)